# There are infinitely many positive integers $a$ such that none of the integers $a, a+1,a+2$ are oddly powerful.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, modular-arithmetic

A positive integer $n$ is called oddly powerful if for every prime $p$ dividing $n$ the max power that divides $n$ must be odd.

$i.e.$ if $p^k \mid n$ and $p^{k+1} \not\mid n$, then $k$ is odd.

Prove that there are infinitely many positive integers $a$ such that none of the integers $a, a+1,a+2$ are oddly powerful.

---

I tried to do it in the following way:

Let $p_1,p_2,p_3$ be three primes and consider the system of linear congruence

$$x \equiv 0 \mod p_1^2, \ \ x+1 \equiv \mod p_2^2, \ \ x+2 \equiv \mod p_3^2.$$

Since $\gcd(p_1^2,p_2^2,p_3^2) = 1$, by Chinese remainder theorem the system has a solution say $a$.

Then $p_1^2 \mid a, p_2^2 \mid a+1$ and $p_3^2 \mid a+2$.

From here can we conclude that none of the integers $a, a+1,a+2$ are oddly powerful.

Comment: How does knowing that $p_1^2\,|\,a$ help?  After all, $v_{p_1}(a)$ could be $3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply CRT to the congruences:  $$a\equiv 4 \pmod 8\quad \quad a+1\equiv 9\pmod {27}\quad \quad a+2\equiv 25\pmod {125}$$

For example.

This yields $a\equiv 22148\pmod {(2\times 3\times 5)^3}$

Of course you can use any three distinct primes in place of $2,3,5$.

Note:  the same argument extends to any (finite) collection, $\{a,a+1,a+2, \cdots, a+n\}$.